# Form validation select field are not validate

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm validating the form using jquery.the problem is phone number, select field are not validate it will not show the error message if the fields are empty.The other fields are working fine.This is the right method what I'm doing?

can anyone tell whats wrong with the script?

Is there any other methods suggest me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 /* name*/ 
 $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var is_name=input.val();
  if(is_name){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });
  
 /* E-mail */ 
 $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
  var is_email=re.test(input.val());
  if(is_email){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* Phone */ 
 $('#contact_ph').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var ph_regex =  /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var is_phone=ph_regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_phone){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* select People*/
 $('#contact_select').on('select', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var selectOption =  $("#contact_select option:selected");
  var is_select=selectOption.test(select.val());
  if(is_select){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* select Time*/
 $('#contact_time').on('select', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var selectTime =  $("#contact_time option:selected");
  var is_time=selectTime.test(select.val());
  if(is_time){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* message*/
 $('#contact_message').keyup(function(event) {
  var input=$(this);
  var message=$(this).val();
  console.log(message);
  if(message){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  } 
 });
 
  /* Submit */
 $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
  var form_data=$("#contact").serializeArray();
  var error_free=true;
  for (var input in form_data){
   var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
   var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
   var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
   if (!valid){
    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;
   }
   else{
    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
   }
  }
  if (!error_free){
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else{
   $('.success_msg').css('display','block');
  }
 });
   
});
```

```css
#contact label{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 130px;
 text-align: right;
}
#contact_submit{
 padding-left: 100px;
}
#contact div{
 margin-top: 1em;
}
textarea{
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 5em;
 outline: none;
}
span.error{
 display: none;
 margin-left: 10px;
 color: red;
}  
span.error_shown {
 color: red;
 margin-left: 10px;
}
input.invalid, 
textarea.invalid,
select.invalid {
 border: 2px solid red;
}
input:focus {
    outline-width: 0;
}
input.valid, 
textarea.valid,
select.valid {
 border: 2px solid green;
}
.success_msg {
 display: none;
 width: 600px;
 height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: rgba(213, 255, 187, 0.7);;

}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="success_msg">
  <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
 </div>
 <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
  <div>
   <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_ph">Phone:</label>
   <input type="number" id="contact_ph" name="phone"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_select">Number of People</label>
   <select id="contact_select">
    <option value="">select number of people</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select option</span>   
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_time">Time</label>
   <select id="contact_time">
    <option value="">select Time</option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:15">01:15</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="01:45">01:45</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select Time option</span>   
  </div>     
  <div>
   <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
   <textarea id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>            
  </div>     
  <div id="contact_submit">    
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Have you tried with `change` event instead of `select`?

Comment: I'm running your snippet and seems it works

Comment: @palaѕн no I didn't try with change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in your code concats the string **contact** with the **name  attribute** of the field. Then your phone field name should be `contact_phone` not `contact_ph`. Similarly check the select field by adding the name and id attribute correctly.

```
var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
```

For select type, the event should be `change` not `select`. Also check your code inside the select event handler.

Comment: thanks it works. now after select option i'm getting this error `selectOption.test is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the Contact_ph to Contact_phone. It will work.
Also you have to do the changes in JS file also accordingly.
Please find below the updated template and JS file

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 /* name*/ 
 $('#contact_name').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var is_name=input.val();
  if(is_name){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });
  
 /* E-mail */ 
 $('#contact_email').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/;
  var is_email=re.test(input.val());
  if(is_email){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* Phone */ 
 $('#contact_phone').on('input', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var ph_regex =  /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
  var is_phone=ph_regex.test(input.val());
  if(is_phone){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* select People*/
 $('#contact_select').on('select', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var selectOption =  $("#contact_select option:selected");
  var is_select=selectOption.test(select.val());
  if(is_select){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* select Time*/
 $('#contact_time').on('select', function() {
  var input=$(this);
  var selectTime =  $("#contact_time option:selected");
  var is_time=selectTime.test(select.val());
  if(is_time){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  }
 });

 /* message*/
 $('#contact_message').keyup(function(event) {
  var input=$(this);
  var message=$(this).val();
  console.log(message);
  if(message){
   input.removeClass("invalid").addClass("valid");
  }
  else{
   input.removeClass("valid").addClass("invalid");
  } 
 });
 
  /* Submit */
 $("#contact_submit button").click(function(event){
  var form_data=$("#contact").serializeArray();
  var error_free=true;
  for (var input in form_data){
   var element=$("#contact_"+form_data[input]['name']);
   var valid=element.hasClass("valid");
   var error_element=$("span", element.parent());
   if (!valid){
    error_element.removeClass("error").addClass("error_show"); error_free=false;
   }
   else{
    error_element.removeClass("error_show").addClass("error");
   }
  }
  if (!error_free){
   event.preventDefault(); 
  }
  else{
   $('.success_msg').css('display','block');
  }
 });
   
});
```

.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="data.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">
<div class="success_msg">
  <p>Form submitted Successfully</p>
 </div>
 <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
  <div>
   <label for="contact_name">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="name"></input>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_email">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="email"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid email address is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_phone">Phone:</label>
   <input type="number" id="contact_phone" name="phone"></input>
   <span class="error">A valid Phone number is required</span>    
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_select">Number of People</label>
   <select id="contact_select">
    <option value="">select number of people</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select option</span>   
  </div>
  <div>
   <label for="contact_time">Time</label>
   <select id="contact_time">
    <option value="">select Time</option>
    <option value="00:00">00:00</option>
    <option value="00:15">00:15</option>
    <option value="00:30">00:30</option>
    <option value="00:45">00:45</option>
    <option value="01:00">01:00</option>
    <option value="01:15">01:15</option>
    <option value="01:30">01:30</option>
    <option value="01:45">01:45</option>
    <option value="02:00">02:00</option>
   </select>
   <span class="error">Select Time option</span>   
  </div>     
  <div>
   <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>
   <textarea id="contact_message" name="message"></textarea>
   <span class="error">This field is required</span>            
  </div>     
  <div id="contact_submit">    
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Here phone validation not properly if i give 4 digits also accepted.

Comment: @Husna Phone validation is working correctly at my end.

Comment: @ Buddhabhushan Kamble by default, all error messages are coming if I type correctly also remains same.

Comment: @Husna Which browser you are using. Could you please share the snapshot for the same.

Comment: @ Buddhabhushan Kamble `chrome` can you tell me about this error `selectOption.test is not a function`